# Where did I get wrong $F(x)=ck\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{u^{c-1}}{\left(1+u^{c}\right)^{k+1}}du$?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

The probability density function of a Burr random variable is given by $f(x)=ck\frac{x^{c-1}}{\left(1+x^{c}\right)^{k+1}}$.
 In order to find its distribution we evaluate the following integral:
$$F(x)=ck\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{u^{c-1}}{\left(1+u^{c}\right)^{k+1}}du$$ which solution is given by $$F(x)=1-\left(1+x^{c}\right)^{-k}$$
In an attempt to evaluate the integral, I have probably made a mistake that I can´t spot where it is. So I ask your help to show me where is my mistake. 
Here is my attempt:
 $$F(x)=ck\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{u^{c-1}}{\left(1+u^{c}\right)^{k+1}}du$$ ,  make a change of variable $u^{c}=y$:
$$F(x)=k\int_{-\infty}^{x^{c}} \frac{dy}{\left(1+y\right)^{k+1}}$$ 
then I made another change of variable $(1+y)=z$
  to get:
$$F(x)=k\int_{-\infty}^{1+x^{c}} \frac{dz}{z^{k+1}}$$
Integrating this last expression I got:

$$F(x)=-\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{c}\right)^{k}}$$
which is wrong.

Comment: The support is $x>0$. Hence the PDF is $0$ for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: @Gary I got it! That´s perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gary pointed out in the comentary, the suport is $x>0$, and hence $f(x)$ is $0$ for $x<0$. So in order to find the PDF it should be evaluated the following integral instead:
$$ck\int_{0}^{x} \frac{u^{c-1}}{\left(1+u^{c}\right)^{k+1}}du$$
which following pretty much the same steps as before, leads to the following integral:
$$k\int_{1}^{1+x^{c}} \frac{dz}{z^{k+1}}$$
Evaluating this integral gives the final answer:
$$1-(1+x^{c})^{k}$$.